# Find non-overlapping polygons in GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame with a column of shapely.polygons. Some of them distinct, some - not:

```
In [1]: gdf
Out[2]:
    geometry
1   POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1))
2   POLYGON ((1 3, 1 4, 2 4, 2 3, 1 3))
3   POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1))
4   POLYGON ((3 1, 3 2, 4 2, 4 1, 3 1))
5   POLYGON ((1 3, 1 4, 2 4, 2 3, 1 3))
```

I need to find only distinct (non-overlapping) polygons:

```
In [1]: gdf_distinct
Out[2]:
    geometry
1   POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1))
2   POLYGON ((1 3, 1 4, 2 4, 2 3, 1 3))
4   POLYGON ((3 1, 3 2, 4 2, 4 1, 3 1))
```

As polygons are not hashable, I can not use simple ways in Pandas:

```
In [1]: gdf_distinct = gdf['geometry'].unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Polygon'
```

Are there any simple and efficient ways to have a new GeoDataFrame with only distinct polygons?

P.S.:

I found one way, but it works only with fully-duplicate polygons and, as I think, not very efficient:

```
In [1]: m = []
        for index, row in gdf.iterrows():]
           if row['geometry'] not in m:
              m.append(row['geometry'])
        gdf_distinct = GeoDataFrame(geometry=m)
```

Comment: First of all, I've tried df.polygon_colum.unique() - with no success, as polygons are not hashable.  Now I'm working around intersects(), when I iterate through all rows to check if any of polygons in column intersects the specified one,but it seems to be not the best way to do it

Comment: Please edit our question to include the code of what you have tried. A well-formatted [mcve] is much more likely to attract answers.

Comment: Made some editing - hope it clears the situation.

Comment: Do you want the unique polygons, or the non-overlapping polygons? As this is not necessarily the same?

Comment: In my case I want to have non-overlapping polygons (just because my data  is possibly dirty)

Comment: If you just want to identify unique polygons, you _could_ do `.unique()` on the WKT representation of the geometry, i.e. serialising the geometry first.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with a list of 4 polygons, three of which overlap other polygons:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas

polygons = [
    Polygon([[1, 1], [1, 3], [3, 3], [3, 1], [1, 1]]),
    Polygon([[1, 3], [1, 5], [3, 5], [3, 3], [1, 3]]),
    Polygon([[2, 2], [2, 3.5], [3.5, 3.5], [3.5, 2], [2, 2]]),
    Polygon([[3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 2], [4, 1], [3, 1]]),
]
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(data={'A': list('ABCD')}, geometry=polygons)
gdf.plot(column='A', alpha=0.75)
```

They look like this:

[image]

So we can loop through each one, then loop through all of the others and check for overlaps with the `shapely` API. If there are not any overlaps, we'll append it to our output list:

```
non_overlapping = []
for p in polygons:
    overlaps = []
    for g in filter(lambda g: not g.equals(p), polygons):
        overlaps.append(g.overlaps(p))

    if not any(overlaps):
        non_overlapping.append(p)
```

Any that gives me:

```
['POLYGON ((3 1, 3 2, 4 2, 4 1, 3 1))']
```

Which is what I'd expect.

But this is effectively *O(N^2)*, and I don't think it has to be.

So let's try to never check the same pair twice:

```
non_overlapping = []
for n, p in enumerate(polygons[:-1], 1):  # don't include the last element
    overlaps = []
    for g in polygons[n:]:  # loop from the next element to the end
        overlaps.append(g.overlaps(p))

    if not any(overlaps):
        non_overlapping.append(str(p))
```

And I get the same result and it's a smidge faster on my machine.

We can compress the loop a bit by using generator in the `if` statement instead of a normal `for` block:

```
non_overlapping = []
for n, p in enumerate(polygons[:-1], 1):
    if not any(p.overlaps(g) for g in polygons[n:]):
        non_overlapping.append(p)
```

Same story.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation and example!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for g in polygons[n+1:]`, to avoid checking self-overlap?

Comment: Shapely `overlaps` returns True if more than one _but not all_ points are in common, so this doesn't produce an incorrect result, but `n+1` will still skip n more unnecessary checks.

Comment: @alphabetasoup in my example, using n+1 inserts the same polygon twice into the `non_overlapping` list twice. This is because I'm starting `enumerate` from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Ah right, I missed that. I adapted this to use `iterrows` over a GeoDataFrame, and so n starts from 0 in my case. Then I append the row index to the list for a later `iloc` (I need to apply one process to non-overlapping polygons, and another to overlapping polygons). I'd be interested to see if you have further tips when doing this with a GeoDataFrame, e.g. `itertuples` instead of `iterrows`?

Comment: I found this code a helpful starting point, but found an error when applying to a real world example of a geopandas geodataframe with hundreds of polygons:
1) I found that only checking polygons from the n index in the for loop to the end (```for g in polygons[n:]:```) resulted in an overlapping polygons being included in the non-overlapping list and the non-overlapping polygon not being included.
I fixed this issue and added some more functionality in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77026442/5972778)  to the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) for the great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47503098/5972778) and [@alphabetasoup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476750/alphabetasoup) for the thoughtful comment. My solution builds upon this answer for my use case, which is finding the overlapping polygons.

```
# Find polygons in a geopandas dataframe that overlap with another polygon 
# in the same dataframe as well as non-overlapping polygons
overlapping = []
non_overlapping = []
for n, p in enumerate(list(gdf.geometry), 0):
    overlaps = []
    for g in list(gdf.geometry):
        overlaps.append(g.overlaps(p))
    if any(overlaps):
        overlapping.append(p)  
    if not any(overlaps):
        non_overlapping.append(p)
```

My use case also required retaining other columns from the original geopandas geodataframe. Here's how I did that:

```
overlapping = []
non_overlapping = []
for n, p in enumerate(list(gdf.geometry), 0):
    if any(p.overlaps(g) for g in list(gdf.geometry)):
        # Store the index from the original dataframe
        overlapping.append(n)
    if not any(p.overlaps(g) for g in list(gdf.geometry)):
        non_overlapping.append(n)

# Create a new dataframes and reset their indexes
gdf_overlapping = gdf.iloc[overlapping]  
gdf_overlapping.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
gdf_non_overlapping = gdf.iloc[non_overlapping]
gdf_non_overlapping.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

For this I made a few code modifications from the original answer:

1. I found that I needed to include the last element so that I didn't lose one of the overlapping polygons: `for n, p in enumerate(polygons[:-1], 1):` -> `polygons[:]` = `polygons`
2. I used my geopandas geodataframe `list(gdf.geometry)` instead of a list of polygons
3. I used Python's zero-based indexing to retain the index location of each polygon in my original geopandas geodataframe `for n, p in enumerate(polygons[:-1], 1):` -> `for n, p in enumerate(polygons[:-1], 0):`
4. I changed checking polygons from the next indexed element to the end to all the polygons `for g in polygons[n:]:` -> `for g in polygons:` since the former method missed some overlapping polygons because it would not check the current polygon against *all* of the polygons (just the polygons at that particular index to the end)
5. I did not store the polygon as a string, but instead stored the polygon itself `non_overlapping.append(str(p))` -> `non_overlapping.append(p)`; then later stored polygon's index to later slice the original geodataframe: `non_overlapping.append(p)` -> `non_overlapping.append(n)`